# Avoid body interference in a parallel plate capacitor

Tags: capacitor, interference

I'm making a parallel plate capacitor.  Each plane is 4"x6" and they are separated at about 1cm.

I am using an LC meter to measure the capacitance, and the results agree with the parallel plate formula.

When I place my hand near the plate, the capacitance increases, which I believe is due to body capacitance.

I've seen people have used guard rings in capacitors to reduce fringe capacitance. In my case, is it possible to place a guard plane on top of the top plate to reduce the interference as I want to reduce the interference from the whole plate, not just the corners?

If someone has done that and has some suggestions, I would greatly appreciate the input.

Comment: Wrap some aluminum foil in forms similar to guard rings.... see what happens!

Comment: It depends how you want to use the capacitor, what precautions you take. In the limit, if you put your parallel plate capacitor into a large metal box, it will shield it from all influence from outside the box. However, it will also increase the capacitance of the plates, which will also change depending on how they are measured with respect to the box. So, what other aspects of the behaviour are important? What are you trying to achieve? Self-learning, demo to others, practical commercial application, what?